# Writing a piecewise function given a weekly salary tax information

Tags: calculus

given the following weekly payroll period information:

[image]

I am trying to build $F(x)$ where $F$ is the amount of income tax to withold during that pay period and $x$ is the amount of wages after substracting witholding allowances

Here is what I found:

$$ 
F(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if }0 \leq x < 44 \\ 
0.1x & \text{if }44 \leq x < 222 \\
17.8 + 0.15x & \text{if}  222 \leq x < 764 \\
99.1 + .25x & \text{if} 764 \leq x < 1789 \\
355.35+ .28x & \text{if} 1789 \leq x < 3685 \\
886.23 + .33x & \text{if} 3685 \leq x < 7958 \\
2296.32 + .35x & \text{if} 7958 \leq x < 7990 \\
2307.52 + .396x & \text{if} 7990 \leq x
\end{cases} 
$$

Is this a correct function $F$?

Comment: No, you have to factor in what you pay when you reach the limit of the previous scale, and have to subtract the upper limit of the previous scale of $x$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Hetebrij, do you mean that, for example, if $x \in [222,764)$, then $F(x) = 17.8+ .15x - 222 $ ?

Comment: No, $17.8 + 0.15 ( x - 222) +22.2$, since the taxes are over the money more than $\$222$ and you still owe $\$22.2$ dollar over the first $\$222$.

Comment: Oh, I see, So, if $x \in [764, 1789)$, then $F(x) = 99.1 + .25(x-764) + 764(17.8 + .15x) $ ?

Comment: Almost, the last term has to be independent of $x$, since you already have more that $\$764$ dollar, and over the first $\$764$ you have to pay a fixed amount of money, which should replace the $764(17.8+.15x)$

Comment: Then it should be $F(x) = 99.1 + .25( x - 764) + 17.8 + .15(764) $ ?

Comment: And you still owe money over the first $\$222$. If you define $f$ over 0-44, then for 44-222, you have to add $f(44)$. And over 222-764, you have to add $f(222)$, and over 764-1789, you have to add $f(764)$ etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better? I still dont understand

Comment: @Hetebrij I dont understand why is it (x-222) + f(222) can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

We want to build a piecewise function $f$ such that $f(x)$ gives the total amount of taxes you have to pay over $x$ dollars.
If $x \in [0,44]$ you do not have to pay anything, so we start by $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \le x \le 44 \end{matrix} \right.$$
If $x \in (44,222]$ we have to pay taxes over our money that is more than $44$ dollars, and we have to pay $0$ dollar and $10\%$ of every dollar over $44$ dollars, so $0 + 0.10(x-44)$, but we also have to pay taxes over the first $44$ dollars, which in this case is $0$. So we get
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \le x \le 44 \\0+0.10(x-44) & 44< x \le 222\end{matrix} \right.$$
Now, if $x \in (222, 764]$, we have to pay taxes over our money that is more than $222$ dollars, which is $15\%$. And on top of that, we have to pay $17.80 = f(222)$ dollar over the first $222$ dollar. So we get
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \le x \le 44 \\0+0.10(x-44) & 44< x \le 222 \\ 17.80+ 0.15(x-222) & 222<x\le 764\end{matrix} \right.$$

Now, for the next bracket, we have to pay taxes over the money more than $764$ dollar, and we still owe taxes over the first $764$ dollars, which is exactly $f(764)=99.1$.
Now repeat this process for each of the remaining brackets to find out what the amount of taxes is.